# spring-boot package jar not support utf-8 file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

I am a Chinese.When I work with Springboot, I found this question.

I create a spring-boot project using start.spring.io, and only add dependency spring-boot-starter-web. And I put a file called "你好.txt" in "src/main/resources/static".When I use sts or eclipse.When I visit http://localhost:8080/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD.txt or [http://localhost:8080/你好.txt](http://localhost:8080/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD.txt), I can visit the file.But when I use maven package to package jar.When I user java -jar my.jar, I can not visit the file.But I rename it to hello.txt, it worked.

Does it mean spring-boot not support not-English file name in classpath of jar.

thank you!

Comment: There have been problems in this area in the past but I believe they have been fixed. What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: 2.1.3.the newest release version

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using 2.1.3 with a jar built with either Maven or Gradle. Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I found my mistake.My Project use 2.0.0, it not support chinese file name.I think it's spring boot problem.I create a new project use 2.1.3 to test whether newest spring-boot has same problem.But I make a wrong compare, the hello.html has content, but the 你好.html is empty file.It shows hello.html can work, whether 你好.html not ,when run in jar, But in sts,it works. Finnally I found The 2.0.0 not support chinese file,  2.1.3 not support empty file where run in jar, whether the filename is English or Chinese. But it doesn't matter, no one use empty static files.Thanks very much.